# How To Use / Force A Default Font

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a specific font that i have used in a certain section of my website design. I know that this font will NOT be on 99.9% of my users computers... so is there a way to apply this font to certain text, without having to use images for the text...

If you can suggest away, can you confirm that it is compatible across all browsers...

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert that font for every browser. There are several online convertes for this job. And then you just have to add it in CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'mwebfont';
    src: url('fonts/mw.eot');
    src: url('fonts/mw.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/mw.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/mw.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/mw.svg#mwebfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

[Here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) is a nice converter

NOTE: Make sure your fonts are legally eligible for web embedding.

Comment: Just note: make sure you have the license before doing this. Often you can't just upload fonts such as Helvetica as it's illegal

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try using [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)
.